# How accepted is it for GMs to "lie"?

Tags: gm-techniques

Many GMs seem to be averse to declaratively stating any categorical untruth about the gameworld. If something that happens in a scene is not what it seems, they describe the event in terms of what the characters see and hear rather than what is actually happening. If they ever relate not-necessarily-true information directly (i.e., without using an NPC), they prefix this exposition with, "You *think* that..." or some other bet-hedging formula. Unless they explicitly indicate otherwise, everything they say is considered necessarily true.

As a player, this bothers me. It tips the GM's hand. It means that any definite, declarative statement the GM makes about the game world reinforces a discrepancy between player knowledge and character knowledge. For any number of in-universe reasons, my character may have a justified belief in whatever fact the GM just told me, but I as a player *know* it with absolute epistemological certainty, not because of any education, evidence, or intuition, because I just heard it from the mouth of God. And when God *doesn't* make a definite, declarative statement, I can tell, and my character can't. Despite this, most of the aforementioned bet-hedging phrases—"You think that...", "You believe that...", "It looks like..."—imply that there is some doubt in my character's mind, even if there is no justification for any such doubt!

My experience as a GM is limited, but my tentative preference is to state to the players as fact whatever it is their characters think they know, regardless of the truth or falsehood of that information—all without any wishy-washy "you think that..." unless I want to drop a hint. (This does not require players or characters to believe what I say; if a player can give a reason why their character believes something else, the character believes that instead.)

This preference is tentative because I've heard GM stories about players who get very angry at GMs who "tell lies"... and the occasional *player* story about big bad meanie GMs who tell lies! Apparently, young and/or naive players sometimes even feel betrayed when *NPCs* relate false information. That one's easy to rebut; every experienced player knows that NPCs don't always tell the truth... but how many of them are comfortable with the idea of the GM himself not always doing so?

I realize that there are special cases, like illusion magic and critical failures on rolls-for-information, where this is common or even normal. I'm not asking about those. I'm asking about a GM style where, regardless of framing or phrasing, all exposition is subjective, and any information that *isn't* subjective is considered OOC knowledge off-limits to roleplay.

Does anyone here have experience with this style, whether as a player or as a GM? How popular is it? How do players typically respond when first exposed to it? Does it take them a while to get used to it? Do some of them come to prefer it?

**EDIT:** According to Erik, this depends on the game (because of course it does; how silly of me not to think of that). What benefits does the alternative "GM-always-tells-the-truth" model have, and for what games?

I'm relatively system-agnostic, but I have a fondness for GURPS and a moderate preference for "simulationist" game styles, in the sense that I value immersion and find mechanical concreteness to be generally more immersive than mechanical abstraction (hit points as meat points rather than as guts points, players interacting with the world primarily through their characters rather than through mechanics that let them redefine the world around their characters, failure on a skill check resulting only in those effects which logically follow from failure at the action the skill check was supposed to represent, etc.).

Comment: This question is heavily dependent on the game you are playing. In D&D it's fairly common for the GM to behave like this, but in Fate it's not really supposed to work that way and in Dungeon World it's against the rules.

Comment: So can you add which games you're playing that you'd like to know more about? You can add a tag for the game system.

Comment: Very good point. Extended my question a bit.

Comment: Seeing how the question was closed as unclear and the question is fairly long. Could it be summarized as : Why is the GMs words usually taken as truth?

Comment: Or maybe : what are the negative effects of a lying gm?

Comment: There is a lot of middle ground between the situations described in the question, and there exist GM techniques that solve the problem you describe without direct lies. Are you more interested in the GM lying *at all*, or lying in the context of other narrative options?

Answer (score 3):

You've written:

> If they ever relate not-necessarily-true information directly (i.e., without using an NPC), they prefix this exposition with, "You think that..." or some other hedge-betting formula. Unless they explicitly indicate otherwise, everything they say is considered necessarily true.

In my experience, there's a GM mindset where they simply hedge *everything* they say with "you think that..." or "it looks like...".

This doesn't work very well for scenery.  It's hard to say things like: "You think you've walked for about a mile, and it looks like there's a river up ahead.  What appears to be sunlight gleams off something that seems to be water.  You think you see a fish which appears to be leaping out of the thing that looks like a river."  When describing scenery, I generally just tell the players what the environment is like. I don't recall ever running a game in which the characters were confused about major aspects of the environment and I had to lie when doing this.

On the other hand, I do it reflexively for skill checks.  If someone says: "I search for traps and I get a 20 on Investigation," I tell them "you don't find any traps."  If they say: "I search for traps and I get a 25 on Investigation", I might tell them "you're confident there are no traps here".

This is just good GMing.  If you're going to say something that might be false, you have to always hedge it whether it's false or not.

My players have never had a problem with this, possibly because I make it clear that I'm not playing mind games to mess with them, I'm just communicating what their character knows to the best of my ability.

You've also written:

> I'm asking about a GM style where, regardless of framing or phrasing, all exposition is subjective, and **any information that isn't subjective is considered OOC knowledge off-limits to roleplay**.

and I have a strong belief that this is a bad idea.

Many players approach RPGs with a "play-to-win" mindset, where they build the best character they can and they use the best tactics available to them in order to reach a good outcome.  If you go to those players and you say: "here's critically important information, but you have to pretend you don't know it when choosing a tactic", it will take those players right out of the game: you're asking them to stop trying to win the game, and instead merely sit there and help you simulate the outcome of the adventure.  Essentially you're removing their agency by telling them they can't make good decisions on behalf of their character.

Unless you explicitly have a Session-0 agreement that player knowledge will be separate from character knowledge, I recommend that you try to avoid putting your players in the position of having to keep the two separate.

Comment: I always say, you don’t find any traps, regardless of the roll unless they do find a trap. 

There may be no traps about at all, or they may not have reached the DC of the trap that is present. They will never know, unless they trigger it. 

Likewise if they attempt to disarm I will tell them they think it is disarmed, unless they roll well over the DCun which case I will tell them it clearly is. My players are really really good at not using the dice roll to determine actions.

Answer (score 3):

## If the universe lies, we're all undone.

In a story, malicious deceptions are there to fail. They're there for someone to realize what they really are and take action to expose the truth and deal with the deceived people. Perhaps not successfully, that's where the drama comes from. In scenarios where GMs describe disguises and illusions differently from real things so players begin to engage the truth-discerning mechanisms of the game system, they're hinting at what's in the story and where it should go next.

But there are a couple of reasons the person who plays the universe should be clear about the truth.

### Is "I've stopped lying" a lie?

So we're talking about a player with an outsize responsibility here, right? Everyone else just has to worry about a single character, but this player gets the entire rest of the universe - and not only that, they're also the final arbiter of those outside-the-universe things called "the rules". You know, how many hit points you have and if you're dead or not.

If everything's fair game for describing however you like, what happens when somebody doesn't believe that they took damage? What happens when somebody doesn't believe that they're dead? What can you say to convince them you're telling the truth?

So suppose we establish that game mechanics are always true when you say them.

### Is "I made a mistake" a lie?

But this has also happened, right? You established the heads of two noble families four sessions ago and now, a month later, when you're describing something, you mix the names up and put someone where they don't belong. There would be intrigue and betrayal and outcry if what you said was true, but if it was the other way around it's just business as usual.

So what happens when someone doesn't believe you made a mistake? Lying is double the work, after all. You have to know what the truth is, and also what the lie you're presenting is. All that work, wouldn't it be easy to get crossed up? We should investigate what's really going on here!

And now they're all going to spend a lot of time and resources trying to find the fault in something that was faultless to begin with.

But let's suppose you can also unambiguously signal when you've made a mistake in your description. That sentiment will still tie into:

### Is "it's safe" the truth?

Unless you're hardcore into extreme urban exploration, I would bet that in all your life you have never, not even once, stopped in your tracks before walking five feet and worried that your senses were deceiving you, that if you proceeded straight ahead you would pitch headlong into a vat of acid and die in agony.

This is a much more common worry for characters in fictional worlds where elaborate deceptive mechanisms are more common. Not the pit of acid necessarily, but any kind of ruinous action, like being deceived into ending the world.

If you're constantly ambiguously describing the world, people are going to take the time to address potentially lethal deceptions, spending a lot of time and resources trying to find the fault in something that was faultless to begin with.

But let's suppose that you're just being initially ambiguous and the other players have fairly low-overhead methods to find out what's really true. There's still something wrong here:

### Is "it's dangerous" the truth?

So there's a lot of research done into alarms and the human response to them. What happens when there are false alarms, stimuli people need to respond to which some fraction of the time don't actually reflect reality? As it turns out, after a brief adjustment to learn, people start responding to false alarms with a reduced impulse, correspondent to the rough amount of time that the alarm actually turns out genuine.

They get **alarm fatigue**.

So if you present a constantly ambiguously-perceived world, even when people can take actions to resolve that ambiguity for themselves, after a while they'll start treating everything with a level of caution roughly in keeping with the actual rate at which their first impressions were legitimately wrong. That's not going to be a high rate, given the number of times they walked five feet and didn't pitch headlong into a pit of acid after all.

And if you do fool them big, all that's going to get you is a little more evenly-distributed jumping at shadows for a little while.